# jQuery Conflict with autocomplete Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i currently working on showing data in my input type from autocomplete. its working well with jquery.min.js file. but it disabled my side bar dropdown because it requires jquery.2.2.js file.

now i want to to execute both jquery files for performing both functionalities.

**here is my code**

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**here is my autocomplete file js file code**

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

suggest me.. what can i do for resolve this problem. thanks

Comment: You only need to load jQuery.js once in a page. Please provide more details

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As was mentioned, you should only load `js/jquery.min.js` once. Your header code should include both jQuery and jQuery UI files and CSS. Plus we will need to see more of your JavaScript code where you initialize the Autocomplete.

Comment: Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery-ui/513/getting-started-with-jquery-ui-library#t=201704031712108685109